# Customizing MVC 3 [Autorize] atrribute with Roles

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, authorize.net

I am trying to implement a registration system in my project using MVC 3.0

Ours is a paid subscription and I have to keep track of payments.

I need to use our database tables for user information and roles etc.

Where I need to start Overriding or changing or rewriting code for my custom authentication and authorization.

Ex: Membershipprovider and SqlRoleProvider and membershipUser ..etc

I want to use [Authorize("Admin Active")] on controller actions. if I want to use my own database tables for roles how can i modify existing AspnetSqlrolemnager according to my database. (simply suggest me some tutorials which explains how the authorize attribute checks for the roles in my database or aspnet database)

OR

is there any other easy way to do this..
All I want to do is creating a user with firstname, lastname, address, state, zip, company name, userid, password, email etc.

password reset..

check for the roles like is a admin or active or inactive users..

for admins i need to provide all users with their roles and depending on the expiration date they can activate or inactive those users.

I know there are many questions in SO on this topic but i am looking for one which suites for my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Custom Role Provider that inherits from asp.net RoleProvider class. Check [this](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/17/CreateCustomRoleProviderASPNETRolePermissionsSecurity.aspx).

Why you think built-in asp.net SqlRoleProvider won't suit your need?

Comment: may be that will..but not the membership provider..even thought i use the existing role provider but i have to create a database same as the asp.net sql role provider..anyway i am not pretty sure at this point to either using existing one or not but i want to know how it is working in the behind..thanks for the reply..